# Getting matplotlib to work interactively on a raspberry PI

Tags: matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I have this code in python running on a Raspberry PI

```
import spidev
import time
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 100000

def readTemp():
    x = spi.readbytes(4)
    temp = ((x[0] << 8) | x[1]) >> 4
    temp += ((x[1] & 15) >> 2)*.25
    return temp


plt.ion()
plt.plot([1.6, 2.7])

i = 0

while i <= 10:
    print(readTemp())
    time.sleep(1)
    i = i + 1
```

When I run this code,the figure that comes from the plt.plot() line doesn't appear until the while loop is finished running. I want the figure to appear when the plt.plot() line happens, before the while loop even starts. Please help me understand why the figure waits until the program is done running to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Change `time.sleep(1)` to `plt.pause(1).`

The `pause` will trigger a plot and will also enable you to update the plot iteratively during the loop.